# IBM Watson speech to text for Android: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Has anyone seen this error? Know how to fix it? Please help me.

I am using the [IBM Watson speech to text](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk) library, and trying to make it record the voice when button pressed, and stop record when button released.

I have read the code sample given, but I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.opus.JNAOpus
```

**fragment where i record the voice**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.MicrophoneInputStream;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.utils.ContentType;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.SpeechToText;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.RecognizeOptions;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.SpeechResults;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.websocket.BaseRecognizeCallback;
import com.zainalfahrudin.noteapp.R;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class AddNoteSpeechFragment extends Fragment {

    private ImageView ivRecord;
    private RelativeLayout viewBg;
    private Button button;
    private SpeechToText speechService;
    private InputStream myInputStream;
    private RecognizeOptions options;
    private TextView tvResult;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private boolean isRecording;
    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_speech_layout, container, false);
        ivRecord = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivRecord);
        viewBg = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rvBgRecord);
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        tvResult = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvVoiceResult);
        progress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressRecord);
        return view;
    }

    public static AddNoteSpeechFragment newInstance(Bundle args) {
        AddNoteSpeechFragment fr = new AddNoteSpeechFragment();
        fr.setArguments(args);
        return fr;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        speechService = new SpeechToText();

        speechService.setUsernameAndPassword("60b15d7e-84c3-4a35-b3c4-dc50ddf9d445", "4ugHjjouy5TH");
        System.out.println(speechService.getModels());


        options = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
                .continuous(true)
                .interimResults(true)
                .model("en-US_BroadbandMode1")
                .contentType(ContentType.OPUS.toString())
                .inactivityTimeout(2000)
                .build();

        viewBg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        //pressed
                        myInputStream = new MicrophoneInputStream();
                        ivRecord.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mic_black_48dp));
                        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (!isRecording) {
                                    isRecording = true;
                                    translateVoice();
                                } else {
                                    Log.d(getTag(), "run: has recording ...");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: isrecording = " + isRecording);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        ivRecord.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mic_none_black_48dp));
                        isRecording = false;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: isrecording = " + isRecording);
                        try {
                            myInputStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                }

                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void translateVoice() {
        Log.d(TAG, "translateVoice: run!");
        try {
            speechService.recognizeUsingWebSocket(myInputStream,
                    options, new BaseRecognizeCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTranscription(SpeechResults speechResults) {
                            String text = speechResults.getResults().get(0).getAlternatives().get(0).getTranscript();
                            System.out.println(text);
                            tvResult.setText(text);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception e) {
                            showSnackBar(e.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDisconnected() {
                            showSnackBar("disconected");
                        }

                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showSnackBar(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void showSnackBar(String message) {
        Snackbar.make(button, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile(name: 'core-release', ext: 'aar')
    //compile project(path: ':core')
    compile(name: 'cloudant', ext: 'aar')
    //compile project(path: ':cloudant')
    compile 'com.cloudant:cloudant-sync-datastore-android:0.15.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //compile project(path: ':analytics')
    compile(name: 'analytics-release', ext: 'aar')
    compile(
            "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion",
            "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$supportLibraryVersion",
            "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion",
            "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion",
            "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    )
    // transitive dependencies are not pulled from local .aar, so we must include all of them:
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:text-to-speech:3.5.1'
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:speech-to-text:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:language-translator:3.5.2'

    compile project(':android-sdk-0.2.1-aar-with-dependencies')
}
```

**logcat**

```
09:34:56.876 8480-8714/zainalfahrudin.noteapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-780
                                                                          Process: zainalfahrudin.noteapp, PID: 8480
                                                                          java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.opus.JNAOpus
                                                                              at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.opus.OggOpusEnc.initEncoder(OggOpusEnc.java:64)
                                                                              at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.opus.OggOpusEnc.<init>(OggOpusEnc.java:43)
                                                                              at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.library.audio.MicrophoneCaptureThread.run(MicrophoneCaptureThread.java:66)
```

Comment: looks like speechService wraps something that gets from the mic's inputStream to a handler ecoding the raw PCM to Opus and you dont have the OpusLib in your gradle dependency. Check/ dump the gradle dependency chain and also check the watson stt sample for the build dependency. U are missing opus codecs.

Comment: library/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/opuslib.so    is where the missing codec is for -v7a build. you will need to review the includes in the build to figure out why the aar containing those .so files is not being included in the apk. be sure you understand how the watson lib is distributed and combined into builds.  ie "using the watson lib in your android project" . For example, if you alter your gradle to include the watson aar in './releases' im pretty sure your runtime will include 'libopus.so' for your specific architecture.